# Arrange images in a grid

Tags: css, image

I am looking for a clean way to arrange images like the following example:

[image: example of how it should look like]

I've tried some ways, but nothing worked for me. I've tried `float:left` and `float: right` for the bigger ones without any success. `position:absolute` worked of course, but is not practicable because the galleries can appear at multiple positions.

Comment: use a grid layout, visit the link @mishik posted

Comment: Have you tried doing it using soms CSS? You are basically asking if anyone can do the 'Dirty work' for you. I suggest reading one of : [THESE](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tutorial+floating+divs+css)

Comment: Considere using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) could help you

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, and why it didn't work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually just use float. see images are inline element you could float the big ones to right \ left and have the other images surrounding them:
**CSS:**

```
.small{
        width:100px;
        float:right;
    }
    .left{
        float:left;
    }
    .right{
     float:right;   
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="left" height="450" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" /><img src="http://www.just4cats.org/images/cats_012.jpg" class="small" />
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jw8dh/1/)

You have to calculate some widths calculations:

> big-image-width **÷** small-image-width **=** big-image-height **÷** small-image-height

In the above case it's 6. `6 * 2 = 12` and you add one for the edge.
So one big picture and 13 smaller ones for each section.

but after that it's a smooth sail.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of float, try to use some width percentages.

```
/* For larger images */
larger {
    width: 66.66666666%;
}

/* For smaller ones */
smaller {
    width: 33.333333333%;
}
```

Comment: The main reason is that 33.33333333% is much more close to 1/3 than 33%. It is a current practice when using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s my perfectly working simple attempt

css :

```
.wrap {
    height:auto;
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.relef {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
.relri {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
}
    .segment {
        width:150px;
        height:100px;
    }
    .row {
        height:50px;
        width:150px;
    }

    .box{
        height:46px;
        width:46px;
        margin:2px;
        background-color:black;
    }
.bigbox {
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and the html, you can loop it as often you want

```
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="segment relef">
                <div class="bigbox relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row relef">
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="segment relri">
                <div class="bigbox relri"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div> 
            </div>
            <div class="row relef">
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="segment relef">
                <div class="bigbox relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div> 
            </div>
                <div class="row relef">
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="segment relri">
                <div class="bigbox relri"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div> 
            </div>
                <div class="row relef">
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
                <div class="box relef"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jw8dh/3/

if all youre images are square you can simply populate .box and .bigbox with images on width:100% and height: 100%