# How many digits after the decimal point are interpreted in stylesheet rules?

Tags: css

So recently I stumbled across [this answer's CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504805/457268):

```
larger {
    width: 66.66666666%;
}

smaller {
    width: 33.333333333%;
}
```

Which got me thinking: How much digits are really interpreted from browsers using stylecheets? As I fail to see a difference already when using 4 digits in Chrome.

I have set up an [example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0pernikus/eyuKF/#base) using the following code:

CSS:

```
body, div {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:2em;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.left {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
    float:right;
}
.right {
    display:inline-block;
    background: blue;
    float:left;
}
.zero .left {
    width: 33%;
}
.zero .right {
    width: 66%;
}
.two .left {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.two .right {
    width: 66.33%;
}
.four .left {
    width: 33.3333%;
}
.four .right {
    width: 66.6666%;
}
.eight .left {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
.eight .right {
    width: 66.66666666%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='zero'>
    <div class='left'>33</div>
    <div class='right'>66</div>
</div>
<div class='two'>
    <div class='left'>33.33</div>
    <div class='right'>66.66</div>
</div>
<div class='four'>
    <div class='left'>33.3333</div>
    <div class='right'>66.6666</div>
</div>
<div class='eight'>
    <div class='left'>33.33333333</div>
    <div class='right'>66.66666666</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just round it to something like `33.3%` and `66.7%` or even just `33%` and `67%`? After some decimals the difference is less than 1 pixel and does not show anyway.

Comment: surely by demoing it yourself in a fiddle, you've answered your own question...

Comment: Theoretically the grammar places no restrictions, `num` is represented by the pattern `[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+`. But of course, it all boils down to implementation, which the grammar does not deal with.

Comment: @Novocaine88 Not quite, as I want to know how it is handled cross-browser or if there is some expected documented behavior.

Comment: @Dancrumb I have posted the code that I put on JsFiddle on purpose. It's not encouraged to only link to JsFiddle, but question and answers should stand on its own. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I think the code that you included in your question highlights the details of what you're asking quite clearly; the JSFiddle serves to demonstrate what you're seeing, but only by it's output... there's nothing in the JSFiddle code that illuminates what you are asking more than the code that remains in the question.

Comment: That said, feel free to revert the change if you disagree. :)

Comment: @Dancrumb If you think my jsFiddle serves no purpose then all of it shall be removed, the link and the content. I won't have the link stand on its own for posterori's sake. Yet I think the code example does not harm the question so I would opt for revert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's really going to depend on your screen. The smallest picture element is the pixel ([hence its name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel)); since all sizes are going to be converted into pixels in the end, percentages are constrained that way.

If your screen width is 2048 pixels, then the smallest percentage increment that can be used is around 0.05%.

I'm guessing you must have a pretty big screen if you can discern the difference at the 4th decimal place!

```
| Width | Minimum percent |
---------------------------
| 2048  |      0.048%     |
| 1024  |      0.098%     |
|  800  |      0.125%     |
|  768  |      0.130%     |
|  640  |      0.156%     |
|  600  |      0.166%     |
|  480  |      0.208%     |
---------------------------
```

### NOTE

Actually, it'll depend on more than your screen. If you have a div that is 10px wide and you try to create a div inside it using decimals, you're not going to be able to see difference between, say, 10% and 12%. You may see a difference at 16%, but that's due to rounding... The principle is the same, it's just the region that you're dividing over is smaller so the differences between percentage points cannot be seen.

Comment: Still pixels though... can't beat Cap'n Maths