# Responsive Webdesign: How many after comma digits for percentage values?

Tags: css, responsive-design

When transferring the fixed widths, margins, paddings etc. of a layout into percentage-values I use the formula: (target * context) / 100

For example: If I calculate with that formula ...

(350px / 1024px) * 100%

I get (depending on the digits of the calculator) => 34.1796875 ... %

How many digits after the dot do I have to use that I can expect my layout to work as expected?

**Is there a rule of thumb at which after comma digit one shall round?**

Comment: Two digits is enough...

Comment: Here's a more in-depth answer to your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594641/how-many-digits-after-the-decimal-point-are-interpreted-in-stylesheet-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend You to use calc();
You can use this function in CSS to calculate for example width of Yours divs.

So You dont have to calc this by Your own, and thinking about how many digits will be good. Just use calc(), and then CSS will be thinking about it for You.

Example of code:

```
div{
     width: calc(350px / 1024px);
}
```

Comment: This does not give value in percentage. And  I think by transferring he means using JavaScript to convert values, not 100% CSS solution.

Comment: @Maciej Have played around with your suggestion. You have to use it that way: " width: calc(554 / 1024 * 100%); " So that you get a unit from the multiplying with 100% . Then it works great. Thanks a lot.